# OnTouch and OnClick Conflict : Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter e1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector, onfling

I have a Recyclerview and that allow user to change scale by swipping up, I use the gestureDetector and onFling for this, this works fine, but then the user should able to click on an Item of recyclerView, i did that by creating an interface from RecyclerView and click actives from Activity, but now I have this error on swipping up.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter e1
> at com.example.simmone.utils.SwipeServices$GestureListener.onFling(Unknown Source:2)
> at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:763)
> at com.example.simmone.utils.SwipeServices.onTouch(SwipeServices.kt:33)

SwipeService.kt

```html
class SwipeServices : View.OnTouchListener {
    enum class SwipeDirection {
        bottomToTop
    }

    private var rootLayout: ViewGroup? = null
    private var layoutToShowHide: ViewGroup? = null
    private var gestureDetector: GestureDetector? = null
    private var swipeDirections: MutableList<SwipeDirection>? = null

    fun initialize(rootLayout: ViewGroup, layoutToShowHide:ViewGroup?, swipeDirections: MutableList<SwipeDirection>,maxSwipeDistance: Int = 1) {
        val gestureListener = GestureListener()
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(rootLayout.context, gestureListener)
        this.rootLayout = rootLayout
        this.layoutToShowHide = layoutToShowHide
        this.swipeDirections = swipeDirections
        gestureListener.MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE = maxSwipeDistance
        this.rootLayout!!.setOnTouchListener(this)
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return gestureDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)!!
    }

    inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        var MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 1
        private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 1

        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {

            var result = false
            try {
                val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
                if (abs(diffY) > MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE && abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)  {
                        if (diffY<0) {
                            onSwipeBottomToTop()
                        }
                        }
                result = true
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
            return result
        }
    }

    fun cancel() {
        layoutToShowHide?.animate()?.scaleX(1f)?.scaleY(1f)?.setDuration(500)?.start();
    }

        fun onSwipeBottomToTop() {
        layoutToShowHide?.animate()?.scaleX(.7f)?.scaleY(.7f)?.setDuration(500)?.start();
        }


}
```

Activity class

```html
class SwappingAppsActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
SwappingAppsAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
    private lateinit var swappingAppsBinding: ActivitySwappingAppsBinding
    private var swappingAppsAdapter: SwappingAppsAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var selectedApp: SwappingItems


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        swappingAppsBinding = ActivitySwappingAppsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(swappingAppsBinding.root)

        val swappingAppViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[SwappingAppViewModel::class.java]
        swappingAppViewModel.generateSwapItems()

        swappingAppViewModel.swapList.observe(this@SwappingAppsActivity) {
            swappingAppsAdapter = SwappingAppsAdapter(this@SwappingAppsActivity, it)
            swappingAppsBinding.rvSwappingApps.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                this@SwappingAppsActivity,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                false
            )
            swappingAppsBinding.rvSwappingApps.adapter = swappingAppsAdapter

        }

            val movingElement = swappingAppsBinding.rvSwappingApps
            val swipeServices = SwipeServices()

            //part where i call the swap service
            swipeServices.initialize(rootLayout =movingElement,movingElement,
                arrayListOf(SwipeServices.SwipeDirection.bottomToTop), 50)



    }

    override fun onItemClick(view: View, swappingItems: SwappingItems) {

        if (swappingAppsAdapter?.getItemList()?.indexOf(selectedApp)==2){

            val movingElement = swappingAppsBinding.rvSwappingApps

            SwipeServices().cancel()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll get a crash like this if something other than the gesture detector consumes ACTION_DOWN events.

Comment: Understood that, any solutions?

Comment: I have the same crash, but using onScroll() and it only happens to about 0.1% of the user base. @laalto do you have any documentation about this behavior ( crashing if other gesture detector consumes the event ) ? Thanks.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238920463